# Using php to overwrite or replace title tag, while using yoast

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I use yoast for my seo, indexing, title, sitemap etc.

But I have one issue, for my product pages I want to use costum taxonomy data and yoast doesnt support that. Now I got the code to echo the exact title I want in the product pages but how do I let it overwrite the title set by yoast, or how do I replace the title set by yoast for this specific post type?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The WPSEO plugin by Yoast has a filter for the title:  'wpseo_title'.  You'll need to add something like this:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
function filter_product_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_singular( 'product') ) {
        $title = //your code
    }
    return $title;
}
```

More info at the [WordPress SEO API Docs page](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/).

Comment: this has saved me after days of looking. Thanks! of there a place where i can find out all of these filter fields? how did you find out wpseo_title was the field name?

Comment: @DanHastings I edited the answer but it needs to be peer reviewed. Docs are [here](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/).

Comment: but how do you add in info from the page it's on?

Comment: Hey @prettyboymp, do you have a similar function that would also work for OpenGraph tags ? we successfully override title, but not og:title with this, and we're getting 404 results when pasting a link on Linkedin (the webpage content is generated dynamically with an API request)