# Where does Yoast SEO plugin sets the site/page title?

Tags: title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, description, wp-title

I am running on `WP 4.7.2` and `Yoast SEO 4.4`.
I want to append a PHP variable to all titles. But it seems I am not able to do that.

I have read that `wp_title` used to be the method before WP 4.4, then it was removed, and then it was returned because of some 'bug'?

I have tried using the `wpseo`+`add_filter` method, but it does not set the site title.

I have searched `/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo` via `grep -r '<title>' *` and am not seeing where the plugin sets the title tag. It did return few lines, but none of them seem to be related.

I found the following code in `clss-frontend.php`:

```
// When using WP 4.4, just use the new hook.
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', array( $this, 'title' ), 15 );
add_filter( 'wp_title', array( $this, 'title' ), 15, 3 );
```

Comment: Probably best to ask them directly? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Comment: If you're asking how to modify the Yoast title, this is a duplicate of [Using php to overwrite or replace title tag, while using yoast](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61472/using-php-to-overwrite-or-replace-title-tag-while-using-yoast)

Comment: I have seen that answer, and I have tried it. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a `wpseo_title` filter you can hook into. Example:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'add_to_page_titles');
function add_to_page_titles($title) {
    $title .= $addToTitle;
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I have tried that one as well, but it is not working for me. 
I have added that exact code in the theme's `header.php` file right after the `wp_head()` call in the header. No change happens.

Comment: There's the problem - if you are putting this in the theme, it belongs in functions.php, not header.php. The title is set within wp_head() so you are trying to filter it after it has already been set and output as HTML - too late.

Comment: That was easy!!! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

### Where does Yoast SEO plugin sets the site/page title?

Yoast SEO plugin adds two hooks that filter the title.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', array( $this, 'title' ), 15 );
add_filter( 'wp_title', array( $this, 'title' ), 15, 3 );
```

The `pre_get_document_title` hook was added in WordPress 4.4, so on older versions, that hook will never get fired.

For versions older than 4.4, the `wp_title` hook will generate the SEO title.
For versions newer than 4.4, the `pre_get_document_title` hook will generate the SEO title.

The `wp_title` hook will still fire on versions newer than 4.4, but it won't do anything because if we look at the [WPSEO_Frontend::title()](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/trunk/frontend/class-frontend.php#L407) method, notice that if the the $title property is already set, it will simply return that. If it's not set, it will generate the title using the [WPSEO_Frontend::generate_title()](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/trunk/frontend/class-frontend.php#L423) method.

### How to change the SEO title?

To modify the SEO title, you need to hook in after Yoast generates the title, but before it's output. The latest that Yoast SEO could generate the title is on the `wp_title` hook at a priority of 15. The title is output after all the `wp_title` hooks are processed. So we need to hook into `wp_title` *after* 15.

If you want to change the title from within another plugin, just add the following code to your plugin:
If you want to change the title from within your theme, add the following toyour functions.php file:

```
//* Hooking after priority 15 guarantees that Yoast SEO has generated the title
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse_258323_title', 20, 2 );
function wpse_258323_title( $title, $post_id ) {
  //* Do something with the $title
  return $title;
}
```